# Iphone Shortcuts/NFC Tags

Tags: iphone, shortcuts-app, nfc

I'm working on a project using shortcuts and nfc tags to timestamp various locations and then append those to a google sheet. I have it working, but I'm hoping to find a way to improve it so that you don't have to tap the shortcut to run it and instead it just runs like a personal automation does.
Here's what I've done so far:

- downloaded shortsheets for the google sheets connection (looked into other ways and it was too much work and shortsheets worked great, worth the $2)
- used NFC tools to write a custom url (shortcuts://run-shortcut?name=NFCscan&input=text&text=Monument1
- created the following shortcut
  [image]

Like I said, this already works great but when you scan the tag you still have to tap the shortcut to run it. I'd really like to be able to use the NFC tag personal automation to maybe auto trigger this shortcut I've created? I know the personal automation only reads the UID you assign it but I wasn't sure if there was someway it could also run my shortcut or get the text from the url and I'm just missing something. I already tried having the personal automation run the shortcut but it fails and you still need to click to run the shortcut. Any help or advice is appreciated!